# JNI: HOWTO FIND 'public interface LocationListener {}' by C

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I want to use "requestLocationUpdates" and set a listener callback.
I got a error like "cannot find [LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) class". pls give me some hint.
here is my code:

```
    jstring gpsProviderStr = (jstring)(*env)->GetStaticObjectField(env, clazz, providerid);
//ERROR:
        jclass listenerClass = (*env)->FindClass(env,"android/location/LocationListener"); //cannot find class

        jmethodID mListener = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, listenerClass, "<init>", "()V");
        jobject listenerObj = (*env)->NewObject(env, listenerClass, mListener);
        jmethodID mReqLocUpdates = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, clazz, "requestLocationUpdates","(Ljava/lang/String;LFLandroid/location/LocationListener;)V");
//Callback? right?
        (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, locMgrObj, mReqLocUpdates, gpsProviderStr, interval, 0, listenerObj); //set callback
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LocationListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) is an interface, therefore it has by definition no constructor. Only the class implementing this interface has an constructor you can call.

You can implement this interface in a self-written Java class and then create an instance of this self-written class. 
If you want you can implement the methods as `native`. This would allow you to handle the callback on location update in JNI.